# Making enrollment system using visual studio c#

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

Anyone know, where do I start on making enrollment system? I got the basic knowledge in c# but, I don't know how to connect it to MySQL, and how to make it print documents.

This question might be easy to answer but please guide me.

Comment: Please narrow down your question if you can.

Comment: You can use entity framework to connect to database.